# How to compile an assembly file as a COFF file for AARCH64

Tags: arm, coff

I have a simple assembly program for the architecture AARCH64(ARM64). I can use the cross compiler toolchain aarch64-none-elf to compile it as an ELF file. How can I compile it as a COFF file? What kind of toolchain do I need?

Comment: Why COFF? That format has been obsolete since the early 1990s.

Comment: I'm trying to compile a Rust project as a UEFI application on arm. The rust toolchain complies every crate as a COFF file and uses ld.lld to link them as a UEFI file. Now I wanna to add an assembly file and link them together. But the linker only accepts COFF file if the target is UEFI application.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you really mean COFF files? Some tools will display that name for any `.o` file, even if its contents are actually ELF.

Comment: I think so. 
I use `llvm-readobj somfile.o` to read the files generated by the rust compiler and it shows:
Format:COFF-ARM64 
Arch:aarch64.

For other elf files it displays `Format: ELF64-aarch64-little Arch:aarch64`.

By the way If I add my elf file  boot.o to the linker, it displays 
:error: boot.o is not a COFF file.

If I remove my file and just keep the files generated by RUST, it links successfully.